# Combines sentences become 1 string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database :

```
---------------------------------------
- id - fileid -        sentences      -
---------------------------------------
- 1 -     1   -   I want eat .        -
- 2 -     1   -   I wanna eat banan . -
- 3 -     2   -   I wanna eat apple . -
- 4 -     2   -   I wanna sleep .     -
---------------------------------------
```

I wanna collect sentences depends on 'fileid'. So the result is :

```
I want eat .  I wanna eat banan .
```

and

```
I wanna eat apple . I wanna sleep .
```

how to do that with assumption i don't know the fileid? thanks

Comment: Anything that you've tried which may have failed? Use a [`WHERE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/) clause and concatenate during a loop.

Comment: why don't you know the fileid?

Comment: i hope theses are just really bad examples.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(sentences order by id separator '')
from table t
group by fileid
```

Comment: One has to stop and wonder where OP's run off to. Maybe OP will bring us back a doggie-bag or something.